# insert multiple rows of data by single submit button using php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I retrieve data from a SQL table, modify the data and store it in another database table with multiple rows & columns and with single submit button I want insert every rows at a time I don't know how to get that hidden value and work properly with that

```
<?php
 include"connect_database.php";
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $amt = $_POST['total'];
         if($amt > 0) {
                $qry = "INSERT INTO attendance(rollno, name, year, attendance, reason) VALUES "; // Split the mysql_query
                for($i=1; $i<=$amt; $i++) {
                        $qry .= "('".$_POST["rollno$i"]."', '".$_POST["name$i"]."', '".$_POST["year$i"]."', '".$_POST["attendance$i"]."', '".$_POST["reason$i"]."' ),"; // loop the mysql_query values to avoid more server loding time
                }
                $qry    = substr($qry, 0, strlen($qry)-2);
                $insert = mysqli_query($dbcon, $qry); // Execute the mysql_query
         }
 // Redirect for each cases
         if($insert) {
                $msg = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("added");</script>';
         }
         else {
                $msg = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Server Error, Kindly Try Again");</script>';
         }

};

if (isset($_POST['select']))
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE year='" . $_POST['yr'] . "'";
$myData = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($myData);


  echo "<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <th>Rollno</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Year</th>
  <th>Attendance</th>
  <th>reason</th>
  </tr>";

 for ($i=0; $i <$num; $i++)
{
$record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData);
echo "<form action=smanage.php method=post>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=rollno$i value=" . $record['rollno'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name$i value=" . $record['name'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=year$i  value=" . $record['year']  . " </td>";
 echo  "<td> "."<select name=attendance$i >
      <option value=Present >present</option>
      <option value=Absent >Absent</option>
  </select>"."</td>";
  echo "<td>". "<textarea cols=15 rows=2 name=reason$i  placeholder=Enter reason ...></textarea>" . "</td>" ;
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=total value=" . $i-1 . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";


}

echo"</table>";

echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=save class=Button3>";

echo "</form>";




 };


mysqli_close($dbcon);


?>
```

Comment: Is your question how to access each row of the table?  I think your issue is here $_POST["rollno$i"].  What I would do is change it like so $_POST["rollno".$i]   By making this change, you can successfully derefence the variable correctly.

Comment: Your question needs to be clear and concise. It is not clear

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
     include"connect_database.php";
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
             $amt = $_POST['total'];
     $rollnos= $_POST['rollno'];
             if($amt > 0) {
                    $qry = "INSERT INTO attendance(rollno, name, year, attendance, reason) VALUES "; // Split the mysql_query
    $i=0;
                    foreach($rollnos as $rollno) {
                            $qry .= "('".$rollno."', '".$_POST["name"][$i]."', '".$_POST["year"][$i]."', '".$_POST["attendance"][$i]."', '".$_POST["reason"][$i]."' ),"; // loop the mysql_query values to avoid more server loding time
$i=$i+1;
                    }
                    $qry    = substr($qry, 0, strlen($qry)-2);
                    $insert = mysqli_query($dbcon, $qry); // Execute the mysql_query
             }
     // Redirect for each cases
             if($insert) {
                    $msg = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("added");</script>';
             }
             else {
                    $msg = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Server Error, Kindly Try Again");</script>';
             }

    };

    if (isset($_POST['select']))
    {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE year='" . $_POST['yr'] . "'";
    $myData = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($myData);


      echo "<table border=1>
      <tr>
      <th>Rollno</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Attendance</th>
      <th>reason</th>
      </tr>";

     for ($i=0; $i <$num; $i++)
    {
    $record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData);
    echo "<form action=smanage.php method=post>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='rollno[]' value='" . $record['rollno'] . "'> </td>";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='name[]' value='" . $record['name'] . "'> </td>";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='year[]'  value='" . $record['year']  . "'> </td>";
     echo  "<td> "."<select name='attendance[]' >
          <option value='Present' >present</option>
          <option value='Absent' >Absent</option>
      </select>"."</td>";
      echo "<td>". "<textarea cols='15' rows='2' name='reason[]'  placeholder='Enter reason ...'></textarea>" . "</td>" ;
      echo "<td></td>";
      echo "</tr>";


    }
    echo   "<input type='hidden' name='total' value='" . $i-1 . "'>";
    echo"</table>";

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='save' class='Button3'>";

    echo "</form>";




     };


    mysqli_close($dbcon);


    ?>
```

Comment: error was in code now check and keep sure this line is added after for loop  echo   "<input type='hidden' name='total' value='" . $i-1 . "'>";

Comment: still no use. i have added that line. still the same error.

Comment: This answer is insecure because it is not using a prepared statement.  This advice should not be taken by researchers.

Answer (score 0):

you are opening multiple forms, for each row in your table on.
This causes your html to be invalid, just start the form before displaying the table.

You could use this html

```
<table>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="rollno[<?= $record['rollno'] ?>]" value="<?= $record['rollno'] ?>" </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[<?= $record['rollno'] ?>]" value="<?= $record['name']?>" </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="year[<?= $record['rollno'] ?>]"  value="<?= $record['year'] ?>" </td>
        <td><select name="attendance[<?= $record['rollno'] ?>]" >
                <option value="Present" >present</option>
                <option value="Absent" >Absent</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><textarea cols="15" rows="2" name="reason[<?= $record['rollno'] ?>]"  placeholder="Enter reason ..."></textarea></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

with this your values will every row will be put into the $_POST-Array, you can access the values via the indexes (I am guessing rollno represents the ID of the dataset).
When you really only want to insert all the values into a table, you can leave the index out. Meaning you could write

```
<td><input type="text" name="rollno[]" value="<?= $record['rollno'] ?>" </td>
```

Instead of

```
<td><input type="text" name="rollno[<?= $record['rollno'] ?>]" value="<?= $record['rollno'] ?>" </td>
```

You don't need the hidden field, you can just count the items in the array.

```
$total = count($_POST['rollno']);
```

Comment: i'm asking about inserting....not retrieve... my problem is to insert a multiple row values by a single submit button into database...

Comment: And my html shows how you can build your form and table to send all the data to the backend-script